# A class implementing two different IObservables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a class with two events, call them `StatusChanged` and `ValueChanged`. I'm wondering about exposing these 'streams' as `IObservable`. Is implementing `IObservable<Status>` and `IObservable<Value>` on the same class 'bad'? Is it likely to cause me (or users of my class) grief?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @MrFox, nope. I simplified the situation for the sake of the question. This is an API from a supplier, which is not yet cast in concrete, I could yet ask for this, but I don't want to if it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing a covariant interface for different types is a really bad idea. Consider what happens if you cast the class to `IObservable<object>`, which is now ambiguous.

I'd rather have two properties `IObservable<Status> StatusObservable{get{...}}` and `IObservable<Value> ValueObservable{get{...}}`. Simple, clean and it mirrors the two events your class offers.

Comment: Yes, simple and clean always wins.